# Use one table for multiple LookUp fields in Access

Tags: ms-access, indexing, lookup

I'm working on a responsibility chart in Access. Rows are projects and columns are project responsibilities. The cells will be populated with a staff member's name.

I made a separate table with the staff members names and used the lookup wizard in the responsibility chart to take the values from the staff member table. After setting all the columns up with the Lookup Wizard I get the error of Too Many Indexes. Because each column is using the same information as its lookup source  is there a way to get around the limit or restructure my lookups in a way that works like how I intended. I have about 40+ project responsibilities/columns to tackle.

My goal is to be able to add names to the staff member table and have them become selectable in all columns of the project responsibilities list.

Thanks,

Comment: Well, you shouldn't trust wizards, and create the lookup fields manually, and only add indexes where needed. Or even better: don't use lookup fields at all. Use forms and lookups on forms to manage your data.

Comment: You seem to be taking a spreadsheet approach. You should take a database approach. You'll need at least 3 tables, tblStaff, tblProject and tblResponsibilities. Before you start I suggest you read up a bit first on databases, normalization and MS Access.